# How can I convert Binary .fits files to .csv files?

Tags: python-3.x

I have fits file containing numerical values of magnitudes of star clusters. I need to see them as a csv file. Any code to run in python to do the trick?
Note: Fits file is not an image file, it is a table file.

Answer (score 0):

why not use fdump ?

fdump -- Convert the contents of a FITS table to ASCII format.

reference
https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftools/fhelp/fdump.txt